# global variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this code:

```
    $(".link").each(function() {
            group += 1;
            text += 1;
            var links = [];
            links[group] = [];

            links[group][text] = $(this).val();
        }
    });

    var jsonLinks = $.toJSON(links);
```

after it has looped every .link it will exit the each loop and encode the array 'links' to json. but the array 'links' is a local variable inside the each-loop. how can i make it global outside the loop?

Comment: Possible dupe ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138287/global-variable-in-javascript )?

Comment: Your question appeared twice. Better to delete this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define `links` outside the loop:

```
var links = [];
$(".link").each(function() {
  group += 1;
  text += 1;
  links[group] = [];
  links[group][text] = $(this).val();
});
var jsonLinks = $.toJSON(links);
```

I should also point out that this doesn't make a lot of sense because you will end up element 7, for example, being an array with a single element (indexed as 7) to the value. Is this really what you want?

What I imagine you want is an array of the values. If so, why not use [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)?

```
var links = $(".link").map(function(i, val) {
  return $(val).val();
});
```

Comment: i dont quite understand the map function. ive read the documentation, but still dont get it. could u explain what is happening? what is 'i' and 'val'? and what does return mean?

Comment: `map()` applies a function to every element of an array. So the function is called for each element. Whatever the function returns is in the result array. The arguments to the callback are i (the number match starting from 0) and val (the array element, which is also `this`).

Answer (score 2):

.

```
var links = [];

$(".link").each(function() {
        group += 1;
        text += 1;            
        links[group] = [];

        links[group][text] = $(this).val();
    }
});

var jsonLinks = $.toJSON(links);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just declare it before your block of code:

```
var links = [];
$(".link").each(function() {
        group += 1;
        text += 1;
        links[group] = [];
        links[group][text] = $(this).val();
    }
});

var jsonLinks = $.toJSON(links);
```

or simply remove 'var':

```
$(".link").each(function() {
        group += 1;
        text += 1;
        links = [];
        links[group] = [];
        links[group][text] = $(this).val();
    }
});

var jsonLinks = $.toJSON(links);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a closure:

```
{    
    var links = [];
    $(".link").each(function() {
            group += 1;
            text += 1;

            links[group] = [];

            links[group][text] = $(this).val();
        }
    });

    var jsonLinks = $.toJSON(links);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a global variable, you can either

**a)** define the variable outside of a function (as already mentioned in other answers)

or

**b)** attache the variable to the window object

```
$(".link").each(function() {
            group += 1;
            text += 1;
            window.links = [];
            links[group] = [];

            links[group][text] = $(this).val();
        }
    });

    var jsonLinks = $.toJSON(links);
```

or

**c)** create a variable without the var keyword

```
$(".link").each(function() {
            group += 1;
            text += 1;
            links = [];
            links[group] = [];

            links[group][text] = $(this).val();
        }
    });

    var jsonLinks = $.toJSON(links);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript only understand two scopes

1. Global: Which is any variable outside the function and variables declare without the **var**
2. Function : Anything which is inside the function.

So i will suggest you the closure approach as follows

```
 function getJSONLinks()
 {
      var links = [];
      $(".link").each(function() {
        group += 1;
        text += 1;
        links[group] = [];
        links[group][text] = $(this).val();
       }
     });
     return $.toJSON(links);
 }
```